# Issue with Quadratic Variation

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Does the quadratic Variation of a Brownian motion converge almost surely to the concerned time interval?

This doubt is because of the fact that the book I am referring to (Shreve $2$) proves that the quadratic Variation converges in probability but later on use the result as if it converges with probability $1.$